# I can't add a widget in a kivy app from python3 class. Error message: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python-3.x, macos, kivy

I have on MacOs this Python3 script:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
class Grid(GridLayout):
    cols=2
    def doet(self):
        self.ids.grid_id.add_widget(Button())
class app(App):
    def build(self):
        self.grid=Grid()
        return Builder.load_file('lab.kv')
app().run()
```

And this kv file (lab.kv):

```
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text:'Doet'
        on_press:app.grid.doet()
    Grid:
        id:grid_id
```

I try to add a widget to the grid from python class by clicking a button, but it doesn't work. I get this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

P.s. I tried this too:

```
self.add_widget(Button())
```

I don't get error messages, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple problems with your code:

- Your `doet()` method tries to reference `ids` of the `Grid` class, but the `Grid` class has no `ids`. The `ids` defined in your `kv` are in the `BoxLayout` class. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.lang.html#ids).
- The code: `on_press:app.grid.doet()` in your `kv` calls the `doet()` method of the `grid` attribute of your `app` class. That `grid` attribute is defined the the `build()` method (`self.grid=Grid()`) and is not included in your `app` display, so running its methods will have no effect on what you see.

The fix is to eliminate unused widgets, and correctly access the widgets that are actually in your `App`. Here is a modified version of your code that does this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Grid(GridLayout):
    cols=2
    def doet(self):
        self.add_widget(Button())  # add new Button to the Grid

class app(App):
    def build(self):
        # self.grid=Grid()
        return Builder.load_file('lab.kv')

app().run()
```

lab.kv:

```
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text:'Doet'
        on_press: grid_id.doet()
    Grid:
        id:grid_id
```

The `grid_id.doet()` in the `kv` uses the defined `id` to access the `Grid` that is actually in the `App`.

Comment: Oh right! thanks a lot...it couldn't work that way!